# Does weak convergence of probability measures implies weak convergence of their density functions in $L^{\infty}.$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading a paper where we have a sequence of probability measures $(\gamma_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that for all $\phi\in C_b(\Omega)$ we have that
$$\int_{\Omega} \phi d\gamma_{k} \to \int_{\Omega} \phi d\gamma$$ as $k\to \infty$  where $\gamma_k,\gamma\in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a compact set.

Assume that $\gamma_k, \gamma \ll\mathcal{L}^{d}$ and let $f_k$ and $f$ denote the densities of $\gamma_k$ and $\gamma$ respectively. The authors then claim that $f_k\to f$ as $k\to \infty$ weakly in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. I am not sure what it means for densities to converge weakly in $L^{\infty},$ perhaps someone could explain?

Comment: Hmm.. is it weakly or weakly-star?

Comment: The dual of $L^\infty$ is the space of all finitely-additive finite signed measures (i.e., you drop the $\sigma$-additivity) absolutely continuous with respect to $\mathcal{L}^d$, and so the author is asserting $\int f_k\,\mathrm{d}\nu\to\int f\,\mathrm{d}\nu$ (I don't believe this holds).

Comment: Note that a density of a probability measure need not belong to $L^\infty$.  Perhaps in that paper there are more properties you have not mentioned.  Also: in older papers, you may find "weak" for what we call "weak*" today.